# Unable to save Matplotlib animations using ffmpeg

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, ffmpeg

I have installed ffmpeg and added it to path, and checked it works in command prompt, but I am still unable to save animations. I have tried creating a sin wave that will animate when I don't try to save it, but throws an error when I do to demonstrate;

```
from __future__ import division

import numpy as numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot as pyplot
from matplotlib import animation

fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = pyplot.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    x = numpy.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
    y = numpy.sin(2 * numpy.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=200, 
    interval=20, blit=True, repeat=False)

FFwriter = animation.FFMpegWriter()
anim.save('animation_testing.mp4', writer = FFwriter)

pyplot.show()
```

When I try to run this it throws the same errors over and over again, I assume as it iterates through each frame;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-
packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_wx.py", line 212, in _on_timer
    TimerBase._on_timer(self)
  File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-
packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 1273, in _on_timer
    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-
packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 910, in _step
    still_going = Animation._step(self, *args)
  File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-
packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 769, in _step
    self._draw_next_frame(framedata, self._blit)
  File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-
packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 787, in _draw_next_frame
    self._pre_draw(framedata, blit)
  File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-
packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 800, in _pre_draw
    self._blit_clear(self._drawn_artists, self._blit_cache)
  File "c:\users\james\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-
packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 840, in _blit_clear
    a.figure.canvas.restore_region(bg_cache[a])
KeyError: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000000009C04DD8>
```

Since it mentioned an error in _blit_clear I tried changing blit to False in FuncAnimation, but then it wouldn't animate in the pyplot.show() when I didn't try to save.

I'm unsure as to where the error could be and so can't work out how to fix this.

I'm using Windows 10, python 2.7.6 and matplotlib version 1.4.2

Many Thanks!

Comment: This seems completely unrelated to ffmpeg. It's a matplotlib error that is thrown. This might very well be a bug. You are using the wx backend, which is not that commonly used. Using either "TkAgg" or "Qt4Agg" as backend, I don't have any trouble running the above, with and without blitting. You should in any case update the question with as much information you can provide about your system, OS, python and matplotlib version, how/where to run this.

Comment: I've changed my backend and now it runs without errors, however when finished the mp4 file still doesn't exist, so this is a new error. Still, I guess this is progress and I would never have known how to change backends! I've also updated with more system details as you suggested.

Comment: Your matplotlib version is rather old, in case you want to get it to work with wx backend, I would suggest to first update to the latest matplotlib. If the error then persist using the wx backend, you could file a bug report. Concerning the issue with no file appearing, this would rather be related to ffmpeg - however there should be some message returned if no output can be produced (maybe it's just in a different folder?) Appart you may experiment a bit with possible arguments to `FFMpegWriter` and also try `FFMpegFileWriter` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Adding;

```
pyplot.switch_backend('backend')
```

where backend is either TkAgg or Qt4Agg solved my problem.

Thank you to ImportanceOfBeingErnest for solving this for me!